# Does on-select trigger fire during/after query-procedure trigger fires?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have a form that I'm looking at, which makes use of stored procedures as data block source. I'm trying to find when/where the block gets populated.

The block as query data source type as Procedure, but the procedure listed as the data source name does nothing - literally nothing. The code in the procedure is

```
begin
    null;
end;
```

Going through the list of procedures in the package responsible for handling the form, I found a procedure which does populates the data.

Searching for this procedure, I found that this procedure is invoked during `ON-SELECT` trigger.

So - does `ON-SELECT` trigger get fired during/after `QUERY-PROCEDURE` event? If not when does it get fired?

I'm using Oracle Forms10.1.2.3.0, 32-bit on Windows Vista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Forms on-line help for ON_SELECT:

> Fires when Oracle Forms would normally
>   execute the open cursor, parse, and
>   execute phases of a query, to identify
>   the records in the database that match
>   the current query criteria.
>
> Use an On-Select trigger to open and
>   execute the database cursor.
>   Specifically, use this trigger when
>   you are retrieving data from a
>   non-ORACLE data source. The On-Select
>   trigger can be used in conjunction
>   with the On-Fetch trigger to replace
>   the processing that normally occurs in
>   the EXECUTE_QUERY built-in subprogram.